# LinkedIn api - get company updates

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to fetch Company updates using LinkedIn's api. Somehow I can't get this to work. I can see console.log("On auth"); in the console, but after that nothing happens. It's like it stops with that function... No visible errors, no other console messages. Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

I'm using LinkedIn's test company which doesn't require any admin permissions.

My code is this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 14characters
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad 
    authorize: true 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="displayUpdates"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onLinkedInLoad() {
            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
            console.log("On auth");
        }
        function onLinkedInAuth() {
            var cpnyID = 2414183; //LinkedIn's testDevCo
            IN.API.Raw("/companies/" + cpnyID + "/updates?event-type=status-update&start=0&count=10&format=json")
                .result(displayCompanyUpdates);
                console.log("After auth");
        }
        function displayCompanyUpdates(result) {
            var div = document.getElementById("displayUpdates");
            var el = "<ul>";
            var resValues = result.values;
            for (var i in resValues) {
                var share = resValues[i].updateContent.companyStatusUpdate.share;
                var isContent = share.content;
                var isTitled = isContent,
                    isLinked = isContent,
                    isDescription = isContent,
                    isThumbnail = isContent;
                if (isTitled) {
                    var title = isContent.title;
                } else {
                    var title = "News headline";
                }
                if (isLinked) {
                    var link = isContent.shortenedUrl;
                } else {
                    var link = "#";
                }
                if (isDescription) {
                    var description = isContent.description;
                } else {
                    var description = "No description";
                }
                if (isThumbnailz) {
                    var thumbnailUrl = isContent.thumbnailUrl;
                } else {
                    var thumbnailUrl = "http://placehold.it/60x60";
                }
                if (share) {
                    var content = "<a target='_blank' href=" + link + ">" + title + "</a><br>" + description;
                    el += "<li><img src='" + thumbnailUrl + "' alt=''>" + content + "</li>";
                }
                console.log(share);
            }
            el += "</ul>";
            div.innerHTML = el;
        }
        </script>
</body>
```

Comment: if you put a `console.log()` at the start of `onLinkedInAuth()` does it log? also onload should be -  `onLoad **A comma-separated list** of the names of Javascript functions that you want the SDK to execute once it has successfully loaded itself.`

Comment: Thanks for responding. No, it doesn't output anything at the start of `onLinkedInAuth()`...

Comment: So `onLinkedInAuth()` is not being called so your issue is with this line `IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);`. Havent used linkedin's api so sorry cant help beyond that - have you tried using a different `eventName` other than "auth"

Comment: Ok. I tried to change onLoad to: `onLoad: onLinkedInLoad, onLinkedInAuth, displayCompanyUpdates` which suddenly gives me this error: "Cannot read property 'values' of undefined" pointing to this line: `var resValues = result.values;`

Comment: So, adding the functions to onLoad seems to do the trick. However, I still get this error: "Cannot read property 'values' of undefined" pointing to this line: `var resValues = result.values; ` - but it still displays the 10 posts dispite this error. Any idea what's wrong with result.values?

The docs are here: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/company-pages#company_updates

Comment: well looking at your code your function `function displayCompanyUpdates(result)` takes a result parameter but you dont pass it one when you call it so `result` is undefined

Comment: Ok, thanks for noticing. What do I need to change in order to pass it on correctly?

Comment: @Craicerjack I solved it by removing `displayCompanyUpdates` from  `onLoad`. Apparantly only `onLinkedInLoad` and `onLinkedInAuth` were necessary. Please leave an answer as you still helped me along the way to get this to work. Thanks.

Comment: work through everything you did to fix this and leave your own answer, with all those details in it. You can accept it at a later stage. Im just glad you got it sorted.

Comment: How to get cpnyID??/.. I found it from Url but not working....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up having this in head - added `onLinkedInAuth` to onLoad:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: 14characters
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad, onLinkedInAuth 
    authorize: true 
</script>
```

That did the trick.

Comment: How to find Company ID??

Comment: It's the numbers at the end of the company's url in LinkedIn, e.g.https://www.linkedin.com/company/3724/ -> the id is 3724.